# django form on submission redirects to wrong url

Tags: django, forms, url

So my code is behaving weirdly,
I have this;

Form

```
<form action="{% url 'button-check' %}" method="POST">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <div class="coupon">
                                           <input id="coupon_code" class="input-text" name="coupon" value="" placeholder="ENTER COUPON CODE" type="text">
                                        </div>
                                        <button class="tp-btn-h1" type="submit">Apply coupon</button>
                                    </form>
```

Url

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import AddToCart, CartItems, AddCoupon

urlpatterns = [
    path('add-to-cart/<int:product_id>/', AddToCart.as_view(), name="add-to-cart"),
    path('cart/', CartItems.as_view(), name="cart"),    
    # path('add-coupon/', views.AddCoupon, name='add-coupon'),
    path('button-check/', views.ButtonClickedCheck, name='button-check'),
]
```

View

```
def ButtonClickedCheck(request):
    print("button clicked!")
```

I think it should just print on terminal "button clicked", but it doesn't and on top of that I get `[17/Nov/2023 14:57:39] "GET /cart/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=w3YQEunqvvx3420ESxj319UeazutgSdGkYEFAHorlUEmDwzbNj2obbOTbDRHJE0y&coupon=Tom HTTP/1.1" 200 46725` and I am not working on /cart anywhere there. What's the way around here?

Comment: 1. Are you returning a response in your view. 2. Can you check the we console for html responses, maybe you're getting some weird redirections.

Comment: Even when I change (action="{% url 'button-check' %}" to action="") It stills redirects to /cart